# PivotTable Show Details Destination

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, show

I know this may be solved with a more complicated script, but I simply want to have the `.ShowDetails` action for **any** PivotTable in my workbook (I have 15+) to send the associated data for a particular Pivot Item to a designated worksheet every time.  I have this script, but I believe I have coded something incorrectly (I am receiving a procedure declaration compiling error when I attempt to execute it).

```
Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick()

Dim WS As Worksheet

If Application.Range(ActiveCell.Address).PivotCell.PivotCellType = xlPivotCellValue Then
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Name = "PivotTable Details" Then
        WS.Delete
        End If
    Next WS
    Selection.ShowDetails
    ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable Details"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple things...

1. I believe it should be `ShowDetail`, not `ShowDetails`.
2. `ShowDetail`
   is a property that needs to be set to True if you want to display
   the data for the selected cell.

The following line should work.

```
Selection.ShowDetail = True
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I changed the script to your suggestion, however I still receive a compiling error for the name of the routine (I derived the `ShowDetails` from recording a macro and double-clicking on a PivotTable as a test).  Is there anything else that would make this BeforeDoubleClick procedure execute properly?